# Reporting on failed REST API calls

Tags: rest-api

We have implemented a REST API that user/vendors can use to submit contact in Salesforce. However, there are instances when the user sends the invalid payload/data that the API rejects right away, which does not create the contact in Salesforce. My question is, is there a way I can create a report in Salesforce that could give me a list of requests where someone tried calling/sending information to API and it failed or should the calling end can see this only?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a new object called `API Errors` in Salesforce and insert records to that object if any API calls fail. I'd also create a scheduled batch process that deletes these records after a certain period of time, otherwise your org is going to be filled with eventually-useless data. Then build a report off this object.

Comment: Did you evaluated eventlog

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is quite common requirement.
Lets assume a sample Rest Service.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/submitcontact/*')
global class GenericContactCreator {

    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(Contact con) { //Can be Sobject or some custom apex wrapper
        //do something
    }
}
```

If someone sends marformed JSON/XML the code wont even reach your apex class. The Java preporcessor will break it before hand. As code did not reach your apex code, you lost logging/debug logs

So what I do normally, is make rest method as parameterless, retrieve raw body from RestRequest

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/submitcontact/*')
    global class GenericContactCreator {

        @HttpPost
        global static void doPost() { 

            String requestBOdy = RestContext.request.body.toString();
            //The raw Request , LOG it, Parse it, your call. You have control to do it.
        }
    }
```

This gives you control to parse or log or do something about it. Also it removes the intimidating SF requirement of having outer layer of JSON /XML same as parameter name . In the above example con.

Comment: +1 for the note on RestContext

Comment: using platform events to log it ensures that even if your apexrest class blows up with an uncaught exception, the log gets preserved

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box, there is no report that tracks "failed" custom REST API calls.

Best practice is to create your own logging service (examples: [1](https://github.com/Szandor72/logger) [2](https://github.com/davidsbond/forcelog)) with one or more of your own custom objects that track any events of interest to you. Recommended implementation: have a `@future` method or an event bus (Platform Events) asynchronously send a message to your logging service. You can then create a report against your own log entries. It's definitely valuable to have this on the Salesforce side because when a call fails, you'll have a record that you can use to resolve operational issues.

Salesforce does have an out of the box mechanism for tracking API calls, it's called [Event Monitoring](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring). It's an additional license and it's not cheap. Event Monitoring tracks quite a bit of stuff...but there's still no adequate out of the box reporting on top of that. Event Monitoring has an API-only interface that is designed for the use case of an external service consuming the event logs and then reporting/visualizing on events outside of SF. In the upcoming Winter '20 release of Salesforce, Event Monitoring [will be able to distinguish custom REST API calls](https://success.salesforce.com/apex/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuetQAC) from other REST API calls. Salesforce built a really simple [event log viewer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_download) but that won't help you, it treats all events generically. It won't show you enough detail (e.g. HTTP response status) for it to be operationally useful. You could grab the [source](https://github.com/abisek/salesforce-elf-browser) of this log viewer and extend it to show you the desired fields.