# Get request and response body from EventLogFile

Tags: eventlogfile, event-monitoring

Currently I am able to view all EventLogFile records from "https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/event_log_files" but I dont see the exact request and response body for API eventtype. 
My requirement is external consumer are using Salesforce standard REST endpoints and we want to trace the information atleast request header coming in ?

Is there a way to get this data ?

Comment: You might be interested in this:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/273080/19118

Comment: Thanks Pranay but here consumer is trying to use standard REST API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is not available in Event Monitoring feature (EventLogFile)

There's a good reason for this: *It could expose sensitive data*

Logging request/response for API calls would be difficult except for custom APEX REST endpoints as OOTB endpoints can't exhaustively be covered with triggers (queries would be excluded, not all sobjects support triggers)

Reference: [EventLogFile API type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_api.htm)

Comment: Can we atleast get the header.. requirement is external system wants to send unique value in header if I am able to log the header I can check if it made to salesforce or not

Comment: you get what the doc says you get. `URI` is about the most identifiable discriminator available. If this is a custom apex endpoint, that apex code can do custom logging. You might also want to use Platform Events to log as even if the apexrest blows up, the Platform Event is published